# Python Pandas: Indexing 2 Rows Before Meeting Criteria

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following Dataframe below:

```
Rec  Channel  Value1  Value2 
Pre             10      20
Pre             35      42
Event    A      23      39
FF              50      75
Post     A      79      11
Post     B      88      69
```

With the following code:

```
idxall = df[df['Chan'].isin({'A', 'B'})]
for i in range(len(idxall)):
print(idxall.iloc[[i]])
```

This is currently giving me the output of:

```
Rec  Channel  Value1  Value2 
Event    A      23      39
Post     A      79      11
Post     B      88      69
```

However, I would like the output to pull all instances 2 rows above every time the Channel column detects an 'A' or 'B'.

Desired Output:

```
Rec  Channel  Value1  Value2
Pre             10      20
Event    A      23      39
FF              50      75
```

Can someone please advise accordingly?

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
idx = df.loc[df.Channel.isin(['A', 'B'])].index

new_df = df.iloc[idx - 2]

>>> new_df
     Rec Channel  Value1  Value2
0    Pre              10      20
2  Event       A      23      39
3     FF              50      75
```

**Explanation:** `idx` in the code above is the indices where you `Channel` column is `A` or `B`. `df.iloc[idx - 2]` simply selects the rows that are at found 2 rows above those indices.

Note that this works as long as your index of your `df` is a consecutive count, i.e. that `df.index` returns something like: `RangeIndex(start=0, stop=6, step=1)`. If that is not the case, start by resetting the index to satisfy that condition, using `df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace = True)`

**EDIT:** Based on your comment, it seems like you are looking to only print the rows, rather than create a new dataframe based on the rows. In that case, you can use your basic loop format:

```
idx = df.loc[df.Channel.isin(['A', 'B'])].index

for i in idx:
    print(df.iloc[[i - 2]])
```

Comment: Okay, thank you!  The only thing is that I need to keep this in a for loop because I want to print out all instances that are two rows before each of the indexes (similar to what I have currently), how would I use your syntax currently within a for loop that does so? @sacul

Comment: See my edits. I'm not sure I understand, though: you want to print out the rows rather than extract them as a new dataframe? Because if I understand correctly, the code I had before *did* extract all the rows that were 2 rows before your indices (it also matches your expected output)